# Unable to compile Impala's front end with maven

Tags: java, maven, compilation, impala

I am trying to compile the Impala's front end (fe) part with maven. However I am getting this error.

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project impala-frontend: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.cloudera.impala:impala-frontend:jar:0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.cloudera.impala:impala-data-source-api:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT in apache.snapshots (https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/) -> [Help 1`]

I used the command:

```
mvn clean package dependency:copy-dependencies -DskipTests=true
```

The pom.xml for this code on github here: https://github.com/cloudera/Impala/blob/cdh5-trunk/fe/pom.xml

How do I go about fixing it ?

I was following the instructions from the cloudera Impala wiki:https://github.com/cloudera/Impala/wiki/How-to-build-Impala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this one out. In order to compile Impala's front-end for the very first time you need to build the whole source the first time and then subsequent changes to the front end can be just built with maven.